# Balanced Binary Search Tree Questions

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm new to c++ and I just created a balanced binary search tree and I just
had a couple of questions.

```
1) What is the efficiency of inserting/looking up/ removing/ from an ideally balanced binary tree is big-O of?
2) How would I order A.go left, B. go right, C visit in pre-order, in-order and post-order traversal?
3) Last question is infinite recursion is one cause of an infinite loop?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you implement a balanced binary search tree without being able to answer these questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1) The efficiency of inserting/looking up/ removing is  O(log2(n)) 
if you didn't understand that I would recommend googling it
2) Pre-Order : Visit, go left and visit until leaf is reached, then go up and right & visit. Then repeat going left and visiting.
   In order : Go to the left most child and visit, then go up and visit, then go right and visit. repeat from start.
   Post- Order: A (visit last) A->B->C
3) And recursion isn't a loop. 
I would recommend googling all these questions/ wiki has good information about binary     search tree
```